I exported the sms.db file from my iphone, however I do not know a way to sort by the conversations. The Messages section is disorganized
I exported the sms.db file from my iphone, however I do not know a way to sort by the conversations. The Messages section is disorganized.
I have tried to use SQLite DB browser and convert it and export but the conversations are disorganized and not nice.
I don't want to use paid software, I just want clean text backups of my conversations that I can easily read through. I have the sms.db file. What should I do? I tried to get chatgpt to make me a script to sort through the file but it didnt work.

Hi - why have you repeated your question twice?
